# How do I get objects in the responder chain to handle `insertText:` messages?

Tags: cocoa, events

I have an `NSView` subclass which implements `acceptsFirstResponder`, `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder`. It also implements the following method:

`-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *) event
{

    [self interpretKeyEvents:[NSArray arrayWithObject:event]];
}`

I handle the messages that `interpertKeyEvent:` sends in an appController class (The appController is the `NSWindow` delegate and therefore part of the responder chain).

This approach works fine for most message generated by `interpertKeyEvent:`, eg `insertNewline:`, `moveUp:` and `moveDown:`, but it does not work for `insertText:`.

How do I get objects in the responder chain to handle `insertText:` messages?

Comment: Could you show the code for interpretKeyEvents:?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the standard implementation by the NSResponder:

"The NSResponder implementation simply passes this message to the next responder, or beeps if there is no next responder."

Two possibilities come to mind: either your view isn't where you expect it to be in the responder chain, or your method signature doesn't match what is expected:

- (void)insertText:(id)aString

How are you implementing acceptsFirstResponder, resignFirstResponder, and becomeFirstResponder?

Is your application using NSWindowControllers or is it a Document Based application?

Further documentation regarding the event handling architecture:

http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `NSTextInput` protocol for your class, then insertText will be called. Have a look at [nsterm.m](http://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/src/nsterm.m) in Aquamacs for an example of how to implement it.